# Displaying accented chars in help(module)

Tags: python, unicode

I have a Python module x.py with a heading docstring containing accented characters:

```
"""Esta librería presenta la función..."""
```

If I try to import x, I have an error: "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xed' in file..."

If I add the encoding at the very beginning:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Esta librería presenta la función..."""
```

the import x command works fine, but then when I try the help(x) command, I get the DESCRIPTION part like:

```
DESCRIPTION
    Esta librer├¡a presenta la funci├│n...
```

The accented characters don't display well. I'm using Python 2.7.6, and I like it, but I'm afraid I don't catch the unicode thing yet.

Comment: I can't reproduce this ... Is your terminal set up to accept unicode characters?

Comment: Try changing `"""` to `u"""`.

Comment: mgilson: I have tried both Windows 7 (cmd, mingw) and Linux (via VirtualBox). I've found the solution setting environment var PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8.

Comment: Well, in Windows it's still the same. I tried changing chcp 850 (my default) to 65001 but only changed the character for another bad one. Furthermore, help() in Python 2.7.6 gives strange errors with that code page (¿Not enough memory?), so not lucky today :(